# Implementing a sorting mechanism with 3 or more parameters

Tags: c#, list, sorting, language-agnostic, icomparer

I'm trying to implement icomparer or some other form of list sorting comparison to sort a list of vector3s.

The vector3s are being compared to a reference vector3 and then being sorted based on their distances.

I can't figured out how to get IComparer to allow 3 parameters, or how to sort my list with a third parameter.

Basically, this is how I'm trying to sort it.

```
Class VectorSorter : IComparer<Vector3>
{
    public int Compare(Vector3 base, Vector3 spot1, Vector3 spot2)
    {
        return (base-spot1).magnitude.CompareTo((base-spot2).magnitude);
    }
}
```

If anyone knows how to implement IComparer with 3 values or where I should look for sorting a list with 3 values, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What language is this? C#? (Edit: I'm adding the `c#` tag as a guess, somebody please fix if incorrect.)

Comment: Looks like c#, although there are some errors and other problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I don't actually know what language you are posting in, I can't identify it. But, this answer is fairly language-agnostic, so please translate back to your preferred language. I have guessed at the syntax below.

You need to find a way to parameterize and calculate your search metric such that any two object `a` and `b` can be distinctly ordered based on a scalar value without additional information *during the sort*.

For example, if `base` is constant for a given sort operation:

```
Class VectorSorter : IComparer<Vector3> {

    private Vector3 base;

    public VectorSorter (Vector3 base) { 
       this.base = base; 
    }

    public int compare (Vector3 spot1, Vector3 spot2) {
       return (base-spot1).magnitude.CompareTo((base-spot2).magnitude);
    }

}
```

Then you pass `new VectorSorter(theBaseToUseWhenSorting)` as the comparator to your sort function.

If `base` isn't constant then you will need to find another way to express your data set, in a way that has a distinct natural ordering; perhaps create some object that holds calculation results then sort a list of those objects based on a scalar result of the calculation, etc. I can't really give you any more specific advice (or even a good example) there without knowing more about how `base` correlates with `spot1` and `spot2` during the sort operation.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. base would be constant and I did not want to declare in my class, so I was looking for a way to either pass 3 values to compare (which didn't work but was the best idea I had at the time) or to create a value inside the comparer like you did. Thanks a lot ^.^

The linq idea looks good but I really need to learn linq since I haven't done much with that yet.

Answer (score 3):

If it's C# you can take advantage of LINQ.

```
return from v in list
       select v
       orderby (v - base).magnitude;
```

Comment: @Jason that's just syntactic sugar for IEnumerable extension methods which are syntactic sugar for static helper methods. The result is simple and legible

Answer (score 1):

This is neither possible with [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), nor is it conventional.

An ordering - which is indicated by the result of [Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - is done against *two* values. This is codified into the interface and there is *no* provision for three values.

A [sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) (or any code that accepts an IComparer) will apply the ordering function *multiple times* over *two* values as required.

---

I suspect that you really wish to "have access to" a common base vector (avoid keywords, btw) in the Compare function; the easiest way to do this is to supply it as a *constructor argument* and store/access it as a member field of the Comparer object.